# Swift physicsbody edge recognition issue

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The following code recognizes the **bottom and top edge** of the scene and the ball bounces off as expected. However, the **left and right edges** of the scene are breached all the time. The ball goes off screen and then eventually returns back if enough force is applied. It is as if the edges of the scene are beyond the edges of the iphone simulator window. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        var ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ball")
        ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(ball)
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.size.height/2)
        let push = CGVectorMake(10, 10)
        ball.physicsBody.applyImpulse(push)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change self.physicsBody size for example;

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.size.width, self.size.height))
```

and change the parameter `self.size.width` as you wish

Comment: I tried changing self.size.width after pasting your code but it does not seem to make any difference

Comment: @user3865727 do you have this problem for both portrait and landscape mode? I am trying to understand where the problem is coming from

Comment: Right now the problem is in portrait mode. I have not checked the landscape mode yet.

Comment: great, we are getting closer to source of problem