# Why SpriteKit doesn't show me anything?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I just started a project and add the following lines of code:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let myNode = SKNode()
    myNode.position = CGPoint(x: 250.0, y: 300.0)
    addChild(myNode)

    let mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    mySprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    mySprite.zPosition = 1
    myNode.addChild(mySprite)

    let myOtherSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    myOtherSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: 50.0)
    myOtherSprite.zPosition = 2
    myNode.addChild(myOtherSprite)
}
```

but the sprites don't appear in the scene. What's the problem here? I checked my code several times, and I think there are no errors.

Comment: I started a new SpriteKit template and replace the default `didMoveToView` with your method and the spaceship appeared. BTW, a typo in the definition of the `myOtherSprite`, should be "Spaceship". Do you run on a simulator or a physical device?

Comment: @Orkhan Probably your scene and a view have different size / proportion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30835844 Hint: read about scene's scale modes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` to your `GameViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method so that it looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Fix Size */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

As Knight0fDragon noted below, this will affect how autoLayout works, so it may not work for all solutions.

Comment: This will get jacked up with Autolayouts,  if everything is default in the project, the scene size will always be 600x600 do to autoconstraints not taking place,  which I believe is the same scene size by default,  but not 100% sure on that and do not have XCode on right now to test